# PHP decryption function fail

Tags: php, encryption, aes, mcrypt

I'm trying to send data from my Android application to my Apache2 server running PHP 5.5 while having AES-128 encryption/decryption on both sides.

The weird thing is when I run the java code on Eclipse to encrypt the data (as a test) and take the encrypted result to decrypt it using PHP on Netbeans, it works just fine. Transferring the code to Android also gives the same encrypted results, but the decryption function on the server doesn't give back any results, it just gives a null, I'm using the exact same code I used on Netbeans which worked.

Here's the code

```
   if(isset($_POST['param']))
  {
    $param = $_POST['param'];

    $param=decrypt($param, "57238004e784498bbc2f8bf984565090");
}
else
    echo "No post Request Received";


function decrypt($encrypted, $key) {
$decrypted = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, hex2bin($key),hex2bin($encrypted), MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
        echo $decrypted;
    $padSize = ord(substr($decrypted, -1));
    return substr($decrypted, 0, $padSize*-1);
 }
```

echo $decrypted gives a null and the return as well.

Example: 
Cipher: 269B3F5A2208C533AACB51243CFB9CFB
Decrypted to: 28

Anybody know what the problem might be?

Comment: wat is the return value of decrypt function

Comment: basic debugging: `var_dump($decrypted)`. if it's boolean false, then it didn't decrypt at all.

Comment: var_dump returns false. There are no return values.

Comment: 1. You've posted your encryption key. You should probably use a different one now. 2. Can you post an example encrypted string and what it should decrypt to? 3. ECB sucks. Use CBC.

Comment: Aside from the security concerns (ECB mode? No MAC?), we can't diagnose this unless you include a sample ciphertext that you're passing to the application.

Comment: 1. It's for testing purposes
2. 269B3F5A2208C533AACB51243CFB9CFB should decrypt to 28

Comment: Have you tried it on a server? It works for me on Netbeans with a local host as well

Comment: I noticed sth as well, If I try to echo anything after using the decrypt function, it doesn't get executed.

Comment: Also, your padding method is broken. If the encrypted data is a multiple of the block size there will be no padding byte at the end and your 'un-padding' method will chop off up to 255 bytes from the output, depending on what the last byte of the input is.

Comment: So your suggestion is to fix the padding?

Comment: Question: Are you using this to [encrypt URL parameters](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/09/comprehensive-guide-url-parameter-encryption-in-php)? If so, read the linked article and *reconsider*!

Answer (score 1):

After reading up on padding methods I can no longer take issue with the method used to pad the input, PKCS5. However, the method used to strip the padding from the *output* still leaves a definite possibility for introducing the error you're encountering.

This is because a 16-byte string ending in `z` [`ord('z') == 122`] will cause the current method to do `substr($data, 0, -122);` which returns `false`.

In order to be certain that the final bytes are padding you need to read the last byte, validate that the last `$padSize` bytes in the output are repetitions of that byte, and only trim the string in that case.

```
<?php
function decrypt($encrypted, $key) {
    $decrypted = mcrypt_decrypt(
        MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128,
        hex2bin($key),
        hex2bin($encrypted),
        MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
    return unpad($decrypted);
}

function unpad($data) {
    $padSize    = ord(substr($data, -1));
    $padStr     = substr($data, strlen($data) - $padSize);
    $padCheck   = str_pad('', $padSize, chr($padSize));
    if( strcmp($padStr, $padCheck) === 0 ) {
        return substr($data, 0, $padSize*-1);
    } else {
        return $data;
    }
}

$key    = '57238004e784498bbc2f8bf984565090';
$data   = '269B3F5A2208C533AACB51243CFB9CFB';

var_dump(decrypt($data, $key));
// Output: string(2) "28"
```

Additionally, the ECB mode is pretty much the weakest you could possibly choose. See the images at the end of the ECB section in [this wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Electronic_Codebook_.28ECB.29) for an excellent example.

Use CBC.